# Javascript window.blur()

Tags: javascript, onblur

I have this piece of code:

```
window.addEventListener( "focus" , function(){
    window.console.log("focus");
} , false );

window.addEventListener( "blur" , function(){
    window.console.log("blur");
} , false );
```

And if I run : `setTimeout("window.focus();",2000);` from firebug's console I get "focus" after 2 seconds but if I run `setTimeout("window.blur();",2000);` I don't get "blur".

Could someone help me please? I don't understand it, it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, but try this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.blur();
}, 2000);
```